# Extracting "http" strings from 100s of .htm files

Tags: extract

I know a bit of php, a bit of python, and I'm pretty savvy on looking for tools, but I can't find a tool or methodology that will parse the htm files and return all strings containing "http".

I KNOW there's quick fix. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in python:

```
def grepFileForLines(self, fileName = "", keepLinesWith = ""):
    fileObj = open(fileName, 'r')
    matches = []
    for line in fileObj:
        if line.find(keepLinesWith) > -1:
            matches.append(line)
    return matches
```

Comment: Awesome.. so I should make file name  a variable that will loop thru the hundred HTML files?